# How to change font of JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to change the font size of my JComboBox.
However only not selected item are change, like that :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3YOY.jpg

So I want that selected item are also bold.

I done a custom combobox classe like that :

```
public class CustomComboBox extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, 
            Object value, 
            int index, 
            boolean isSelected, 
            boolean cellHasFocus) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel(){
            public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
                return new Dimension(200, 80);
            }       
        };
        label.setText(String.valueOf(value));
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));

        return label;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"So I want that selected item are also bold."* So .. where in that code does it use the value of `isSelected` to do anything differently? We expect a certain minimum standard of effort for answer on this Q&A site, and it's in excess of what is seen above. General tip: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: Not the answer to your question but, you renderer already JLabel. Don't create a new JLabel. This defeats the purpose of using a renderer. The point of using a renderer is that each cell can share the same component so it is very effective in using resources. Your code creates a new JLabel every time a cell needs to be rendered which is wasting resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set font for combo box. Something like this:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxRenderer;

/**
 * <code>ComboTest</code>.
 */
public class ComboTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ComboTest()::startUp);
    }

    private void startUp() {
        JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"A", "B", "C"});
        combo.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 30));
        combo.setRenderer(new ComboRenderer());
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Combo test");
        frm.add(combo);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class ComboRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 80);
        }
    }
}
```

When my suggstion is not helpful in your case please create a small runnable example, so we can also start and debug it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set font for Combo box by using
combo.setFont(new FontUIResource("Roboto",Font.PLAIN,12);